# VIm. VScode. Как мне изменить команду поиска слова '/' на свою команду?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim

Не получается найти в настройках эту команду. Мучает расположение такой полезной функции. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Таки vim или vscode? Или какой-то vim-mode в vscode?

Comment: vscode. расширение vim. https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim.git

Comment: `:nmap y /` — и нажатие `y` в нормальном режиме будет эквивалентно нажатию `/`. конечно, если то, что вы используете — не сильно кастрированный *vim*.